# Formatting out a column value - mm:ss.hh

Tags: mysql

I have a time in seconds and I want to convert it to the following formats possibilities:

```
121.17 -> 2:01.17 |
34.28 -> 34.28 |
133.56 -> 2:13.56
```

I am using the following:

```
IF(Time > 60, CONCAT(FLOOR(Time/60), ":", Time - (FLOOR(Time/60)*60)),
   Time) as TTime,

Results:
2:1.17 (incorrect) | 
34.28 (correct) | 
2:13.56 (correct)
```

I tried a number of things (LPAD, CONVERT, etc)

Please advise. MySQL 5.6.17

Answer (score 2):

You could convert to time by adding the seconds to a constant date and then subtracting it:

```
select timediff(cast(date_add('2001-01-01', interval t.time second)
                     as datetime(3)),
                cast('2001-01-01' as datetime(3))
               ) as ttime
from tableX as t ;
```

You can then format the `time(3)` result with the available time formatting function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server you could do it like this:

```
    SELECT cast(dateadd(millisecond,@val*1000,'1/1/1900') as time)
```

It returns a datatype time but from there you can convert it into a string as needed.

Comment: I have the data in SECONDS and I am formatting it for output a MM:SS.hh - not sure if this works

Comment: I'm afraid my suggestion is for SQL Server.  I wouldn't know how to do MySQL.  But in general since you have hundreds of a second and if MySQL has a similar function to dateadd the easiest thing to do is multiply by 1000 and use milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(121.17);
+---------------------+
| SEC_TO_TIME(121.17) |
+---------------------+
| 00:02:01.17         |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Stripping off the leading zeros is another issue.